# Infinite loop over collection

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I iterate over a std::vector in an infinite way? Suppose that I have

```
std::vector<int> myvect {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

I want to loop it like `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1...`

There are multiple ways of course, but I'd like know if there is a standard / elegant way to do this. I've looked in `<algorithm>` but I could not find a thing.

Thanks.

Comment: make a while(1) around and reset the iterator everytime?

Comment: Do you really want an infinite loop? **Or do you just want to get elements again and again and when there is no other elements - start from the begining?** - well check out http://ideone.com/RLJ7am how to do that - if you really want infinite loop, just remove the condition with breakCount :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no absolute standard way.

I'd write it as follows:

```
for(;;)   // the standard/traditional way to write "forever"
{
    for(auto x : myvect)  // the new way to iterate over a vector
    {
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank. I wanted to know if there was something like "repeatedly" and "repeat" found in clojure that generate an infinite list from a list.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. As **@Debasish Jana** already pointed out you can write

```
while ( true )
{
   for ( int x : myvect ) std::cout << x << ", ";
}
```

I suppose that instead of `std::vector<i> myvect {1, 2, 3, 4};` you meant `std::vector<int> myvect {1, 2, 3, 4};`

Or you can write

```
for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < nyvect.size(); i = ( i + 1 ) % myvect.size() )
{
   std::cout << x << ", ";
}
```

This loop will not be executed if the vector is empty.

And so on.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true) {
  // iterate myvect 
  for (int i=0; i<myvect.size(); i++) {
     std::cout << myvect[i] << ", ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Clarify `// iterate myvect` please.

Comment: Hmm, why not with an iterator?

Comment: this is also an iterator, or else you may use as @demonking suggested

Answer (score 1):

```
index = 0;
while(true)
{
    //Access your vector element using index
    index = ( index + 1 ) % length;
}
```

where length is the total number of elements you have.

Answer (score 0):

c++:

```
std::vector<int> myvect {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int>::iterator vecIter = myvect.begin();
while(1){
    for(vecIter = myvect.begin();vecIter != myvect.end();++vecIter){
        std::cout << *vecIter << " " << ;
    }

}
```

c++11x:

```
std::vector<int> myvect {1, 2, 3, 4};
while(1){
    for(int i :myvect){
        std::cout << i << " " << ;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would move the iterator initialization into the for loop header.

Comment: why that? the iterator will be set to the begin everytime, why should i initialize a variable everytime?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
#include <iterator>

template<class Container> class ever_t {
  struct iterator {
    typename Container::iterator b, e, v;
    iterator& operator++() { ++v; if( v == e ) v = b; return *this; };
    iterator operator!() { return {b, e, e}; };
    bool operator!=(const iterator& o) { return b != o.b || e != o.e || v != o.v; };
    typename Container::iterator::reference operator*() { return *v; };
  } b;
public:
  ever_t(Container& c_) : b{std::begin(c_), std::end(c_), std::begin(c_)} {};
  iterator begin() { return b; }
  iterator end() { return !b; }
};

template<class Container> ever_t<Container> ever(Container& c) { return ever_t<Container>(c); }

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::cout << "oi" << std::endl;
  std::vector<int> i { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  std::vector<int> empty;

  for( auto x: ever(empty) ) { // never enters here
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
  for( auto x: ever(i) ) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**Altough** besides being overkill, you'll eventually need a `break` somewhere so your program can stop. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
for(unsigned i=0;true;++i)
    do_something( myvect[i%4] );
```

will do it

Comment: for vector-sizes that UINT_MAX is not divisible with, there will be a 'hiccup' every time `i` wraps, thou.